# Avoid Printing HTML tag on ASP.NET

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net

I'm trying to find a way to avoid printing (either through a printer or to a PDF file) a specific HTML tag on my ASP.NET project view file.

Is there any HTML or CSS attribute which allows me to do that? How should it be set?

I've tried to follow some answers on other similar questions here at StackOverflow and none of them worked.

Here is the HTML code I'm trying to hide on printing.

```
<a href="@Url.Action(/*att1*/,/*att2*/)"﻿>PRINT</a>
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, there's several selectors for that. Example;

```css
@media print {

  a[href*="@Url.Action(/*att1*/,/*att2*/)"] {
    font-size: 150%;
    color: red;
    /*display: none;*/
  }

}
```

```html
<a href="@Url.Action(/*att1*/,/*att2*/)">PRINT</a>
```

Or in your case specifically, you would just add say `display: none;` to the CSS block in the example.

Comment: Sorry I assumed you already had the media query, updated answer.

Comment: To note: this css definition must be in a .cshtml file. css files will not execute razor helpers.

Comment: @TravisJ It's not a razor helper amigo, just good ol css3, could be in a .css file attributed to the html via rel="stylesheet" etc, or just plopped in via `<style>...</style>` if you wanted.

Comment: Well, it is not exactly what I'm looking for. The tag I mentioned is the one which prints the document. This tag should be visible while viewing the web page at the web browser, but should not be on the printed document. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: @StefanoGuimarãesFalce if you have it embedded in a media query, eg the `@media print {...}` then the style that supplies the display change should only get invoked on print.

Comment: All CSS statements are included at the same cshtml file, inside a <style></style> block.

Comment: That's fine, you should be able to literally copy paste the example in there and it should work as described (provided you replace `/*att1*/,/*att2*/` with the real values or reform the selector to be more agnostic of it's attributes and ensure you use the print media query.

Comment: @ChrisW. I've done that and it didn't work as I wanted. The <a> tag became hidden while viewing the webpage, so I couldn't click it and print the document. As I mentioned, I wish it could be visible at the web browser but hidden at the printed document.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/140115/discussion-between-stefano-guimaraes-falce-and-chris-w).

Comment: Sorry man can't chat for a bit just left office and on my mobile. But if you have it like I show then that definitely shouldn't happen and it should work as you just described it.

Comment: Well, now it works. There was a conflicting declaration on my css statements.

Answer (score -1):

Sorry, I thought you meant hiding your html code, that's why shared those javascript encryptions. I found this website during a search for your answer, it seems this guy had the same problem like you. I hope this would solve your problem.

[Printing Page not printing link/button](https://css-tricks.com/quick-tip-making-a-print-this-page-button/)

Comment: The '<a> tag I mentioned is the one which prints the document. This tag should be visible while viewing the web page at the web browser, but should not be on the printed document. Can I do that through Javascript/Node?